# infinite gradient animation in ion-content pure css ionic 4

Tags: sass, ionic4

I want to animate `ion-content` of page template in my Ionic 4 project. Something like this:

```css
.ion-content{
  height:400px;
  width:250px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: Gradient 7s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ion-content"></div>
```

Above I want the same animation in `ion-content` with pure `SCSS`

Comment: What do you mean `with pure SCSS`? This is already a valid `SCSS` code.

Comment: but this is not working in `ion-content`

Comment: from pure scss I mean not using any scripts like javascript for animation

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it, the code works on the snippet so if it doesn't work on your project the problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: `ion-content` doesn't support `background` property. We need to give `--background`

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and finally found a way to animate the background of ion-content.

Indeed, animation inside --background variable doesn't work.
You just have to add `--background: unset;` in your code.

Complete solution:
In the root of your ionic app in /global.scss, add this

```
ion-content {
--background: unset;
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
background-size: 400% 400%;
animation: gradient 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
0% {
 background-position: 0% 50%;
}

50% {
 background-position: 100% 50%;
}

100% {
 background-position: 0% 50%;
}
}
```

Worked on my ionic version 6.20.4